# for:each loop in IBM Webphere application server 6.1

Tags: jsp, foreach, websphere, java-5

I have developed a web application and created war file using Netbeans 6.9. I had used Java 5 features extensively, in both jsp's and java files. After deployment while viewing a jsp page that contained for:each loop, I am getting error message saying that,

> ```
> 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 5.0
> ```

I had read that WAS6.1 has support for Java5 features. Also checked the jdk version in java/bin, and it is IBM jdk 1.5.

I had also tried the instructions given in [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rweb_jspengine.html). My doubt is there any settings to be done, while creating `war` file to make the deployment compatible with Java 5. Or is there any server/application level settings to be done in IBM WAS console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, the problem is the [WAS 6.1 JSP engine](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/cweb_jspengine.html) which is based on [JSP 2.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr152/index.html) (targeted at Java 1.3). I assume you've found the right parameter:

> **jdkSourceLevel**
>
> This JSP engine parameter is
>   introduced in WebSphere Application
>   Server version 6.1 to support JDK 5.
>   This parameter should be used instead
>   of the compileWithAssert parameter,
>   although compile WithAssert still
>   works in version 6.1. The default
>   value for this parameter is 13. This
>   parameter requires regeneration of
>   Java source. The following are
>   jdkSourceLevel paramater values:
>
> - **13** (default) - This value will disable all new language features of
>     JDK 1.4 and JDK 5.0.
> - **14** - This value will enable the use of the assertion facility and will
>     disable all new language features of
>     JDK 5.0.
> - **15** - This value will enable the use of the assertion facility and all
>     new language features of JDK 5.0.

I assume you've set this in [the right place](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/cweb_jspengine.html) with the correct case and restarted the server. I would also check that your web.xml [declares the Servlet 2.4 schema](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rweb_webxf.html) in case this affects the JSP engine. Failing that, check the support site for fixes.

You should be able to precompile your JSPs using the [JspBatchCompiler](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rweb_jspbchtl.html) or the [Ant task](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rweb_jspant.html) if all else fails.

---

*I would question why you're using scriptlets at all, but that is a different conversation.*

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. I will be able to check this out in the next deployment only. Will give you feedback after that.